# ExpressJS deployed on cpanel server getting error 500 on post

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel

The code I am running works fine on localhost with no errors. I have deployed the ExpressJs server on to my hosted cpanel. The get function works on the API URL.

[image: Express server]

Here's the code for the ExpressJS post method:

```
nftRoutes.post('/nft/addNFT', (request, response) => {
    var existNFTs = getNFTData();
    const newAddress = request.headers['account'];

    if (!existNFTs[newAddress]) {
        existNFTs[newAddress] = {};
    } else {
        existNFTs[newAddress] = {};
    }
    
    const nftList = request.body.nftList;

    console.log('nftList:', nftList);

    for (const contractAddress in nftList) {
        console.log(`Contract in nftList: ${contractAddress}`);
        if (!existNFTs[newAddress][contractAddress]) {
            existNFTs[newAddress][contractAddress] = [];
        } else {
            existNFTs[newAddress][contractAddress] = [];
        }
    
        const nfts = nftList[contractAddress];
        for (const nft of nfts) {
            console.log(`Contract in nft of nftList: ${nft.tokenId}`);

            // Check if the token already exists in the list
            const tokenExists = existNFTs[newAddress][contractAddress].some(existingToken => {
                return existingToken.tokenId === nft.tokenId;
            });

            if (!tokenExists) {
                existNFTs[newAddress][contractAddress].push({
                    tokenType: nft.tokenType,
                    tokenId: nft.tokenId,
                    tokenUri: nft.tokenUri
                }); 
            } else {
                console.log(`Token ${nft.tokenId} already exists`);
            }
        }
            
    }
```

Here's code for axios I am using to post the data

```
const API_URL = 'https://demo.******.com/api'; 

/ Add NFT data
export const addNFTData = async (account, nftList) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/nft/addNFT`, {
            nftList
        }, {
            headers: {
                'account': account
            }
        });
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

When I enter the URL for `/nft/addNFT` I am getting this error in browser:

[image: ADDNFT ERROR]